# return object task on web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a web service which is supposed to run an async task. This async task should iterate through an array of records and process them. Each record to be processed generates a result. What I want is to concatenate in a list these results. When the web service is called, I want to retrieve such list from the HttpResponse of the caller but I do not have an idea how to do it.

The code of the caller function is:

```
private void ProcessRecords(List<Record> recordList)
    {
                //The WS is called and a response is awaited
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/mycontroller/myws/", recordList).Result;                    
                //TODO: Read the result list from the http response
    }
```

The code of my Web Service is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("myws")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> WebServiceMethod()
    {
        var jsonString = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<Record> recordList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(jsonString); 
        Task<Result> resultTask = CreateTaskToProcessRecords(recordList);

        //TODO I Do not now what to return here in order 
        //for it to contain the resultTask variable and later await it in the user function
    }

private Task<List<Result>> CreateTaskToProcessRecords(List<Record> recordList)
    {   
        var newTask = Task.Run<List<Result>>(() =>
        {
            List<Result> resultList = new List<Result>();
            try
            {
                foreach(Record record in recordList)
                {
                 var result = DoSomething(record);
                 resultList.Add(result);
                }
                return resultList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return resultList;
            }
        });
        return newTask;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to somehow return a Task> to the function that calls the web service so that the whole processing done in the web service "newTask" remains asynchronous.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks
Luis.

Comment: Don't return a Task like that, just call it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

All your work is synchronous. There's no need for `async` or `await` here, so don't use them. (And as a general rule, avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET).

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("myws")]
public IHttpActionResult WebServiceMethod()
{
    var jsonString = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<Record> recordList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(jsonString);
    var results = ProcessRecords(recordList);
    return Json(results);
}

private List<Result> ProcessRecords(List<Record> recordList)
{   
    List<Result> resultList = new List<Result>();
    try
    {
        foreach(Record record in recordList)
        {
             var result = DoSomething(record);
             resultList.Add(result);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Note that you can still consume it asynchronously on the client:

```
private async Task ProcessRecordsAsync(List<Record> recordList)
{
    // The WS is called and a response is awaited
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/mycontroller/myws/", recordList);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Result>>();
}
```